# find and rename base directory and files under each basedir, add a prefix

Tags: linux, bash, find, batch-rename

I would like to recursively rename all matching directories and files under a path with a prefix that depend from the current directory.

```
.
├── G1_BIN_REFINEMENT
│   └── marker_genes
│       └── identify
│           └── intermediate_results
│               └── marker_genes
│                   ├── bin.1
│                   │   ├── ab.txt
│                   │   └── cd.txt
│                   └── bin.2
│                       ├── ab.txt
│                       └── cd.txt
├── G2_BIN_REFINEMENT
│   └── marker_genes
│       └── identify
│           └── intermediate_results
│               └── marker_genes
│                   ├── bin.1
│                   │   ├── ab.txt
│                   │   └── cd.txt
│                   └── bin.2
│                       ├── ab.txt
│                       └── cd.txt
```

Under the directory `G1_BIN_REFINEMENT` the prefix will be `G1_`.
The files and directories to be modified are `bin.1`, `bin.1/ab.txt`, `bin.1/cd.txt`, `bin.2`...

The expected result are

```
in the dir G1_BIN_REFINEMENT
bin.1        ---> G1_bin.1 
bin.1/ab.txt ---> G1_bin.1/G1_ab.txt
...
in the dir G2_BIN_REFINEMENT
bin.1        ---> G2_bin.1 
bin.1/ab.txt ---> G2_bin.1/G2_ab.txt
...
```

However, the output is a prefix added to root directory and I am getting `G1_G1_BIN_REFINEMENT/marker_genes/identify/intermediate_results/marker_genes/`

Here is my syntax,

```
for d in *_BIN_REFINEMENT/marker_genes/identify/intermediate_results/marker_genes/
do
#get sample name from path
sample=$(echo $d | cut -d/ -f1 | cut -d_ -f1)
echo $sample
  
#to recursively rename dir and files
find $d -exec env var=$sample rename -n 's/^/$ENV{var}_/' '{}' \+
done
```

Comment: Work before on filenames then on directory ones (else you can have problem to find them). In general it is usually better to avoid to parse the `ls` output, this means the filenames too mainly because special characters and newline, are allowed in the filename and can be interpreted by the shell.  If I correctly understand your modifications will be only in the `marker_genes` directories under `G*_BIN_REFINEMENT/marker_genes/identify/intermediate_results`. Adding G1_ or G2_ as prefix.  ps> welcome  on SuperUser.

Comment: Also, implemented using find renaming files first followed by dir

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in *_BIN_REFINEMENT/marker_genes/identify/intermediate_results/marker_genes/bin*
do
#get sample name from path
sample=$(echo $d | cut -d/ -f1 | cut -d_ -f1)
echo $sample

#rename files first and then directories
find $d -type f -exec env var=$sample rename -d 's/^/$ENV{var}_/' '{}' \+
find $d -type d -exec env var=$sample rename -d 's/^/$ENV{var}_/' '{}' \+

done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we recreate your structure in a `TesT` directory

```
mkdir TesT; cd TesT
mkdir -p G{1,2}_BIN_REFINEMENT/marker_genes/identify/intermediate_results/marker_genes/bin.{1,2}
touch G{1,2}_BIN_REFINEMENT/marker_genes/identify/intermediate_results/marker_genes/bin.{1,2}/{ab.txt,cd.txt}
```

The output of `tree` will confirm

```
├── G1_BIN_REFINEMENT
│   └── marker_genes
│       └── identify
│           └── intermediate_results
│               └── marker_genes
│                   ├── bin.1
│                   │   ├── ab.txt
│                   │   └── cd.txt
│                   └── bin.2
│                       ├── ab.txt
│                       └── cd.txt
```

Then we write a script for your specific case

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e               # You will interrupt script on 1st error
OldDir=$(pwd)        # Here we save our current position   
for d in *_BIN_REFINEMENT/marker_genes/identify/intermediate_results/marker_genes/
do                   # below you get sample name from path
sample=$(echo $d | cut -d/ -f1 | cut -d_ -f1)
echo "# sample $sample"
# ------------------------------------------------------------ #
# find "$d"          # Commented out: from this output you may #
#                    # understand why your results.            #
# ------------------------------------------------------------ #
cd "$d"              # You enter in the current dir
  for d2 in bin* 
  do 
   cd "$d2"          # You enter in the current bin.xx subdir
    for fn in *.txt  # You cycle on each file
    do
       mv -i "$fn" "${sample}_$fn" # Only adding a prefix on file
    done
   cd -              # You come back to the previous dir
   mv -i "$d2" "${sample}_$d2"     # Only adding a prefix on dir
  done
cd "$OldDir"         # Here you come back where you take "d"
done
exit 0               # All good...
```

**Notes**

- Since you are moving files better to be safe than sorry (`set -e`  and `mv -i` interactive)
- Be curious: more info with `man mv` and `help set`...

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation and help.

Comment: @user1967473 In my experience it is better to have _generators_ for the names so that you can rebuild the full path/name starting from variables. Something like a function GiveMeName $Sample $Nbin ---> `G${Sample}_BIN_REFINEMENT/marker_genes/id.../bin.${Nbin}`, and it is even better when the numbers are in the format 001, 002 etc etc because they will be more naturally shown by a simple `ls`. You can format them via `printf`. Eg try  `printf  "G%.3d_BIN_REFINEMENT/mark.../bin.%.3d/ab.txt" 2 1 `: note that you do not want an endline (`\n`) at the end of the name...